# VPN Environment on non VLAN Netwoking in OpenStack

Tags: vpn, openstack, dhcp, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I have read the VPN ability of OpenStack here:
[Cloudpipe – Per Project Vpns](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/devref/cloudpipe.html)

One simple question: Is it possible to implement a VPN environment on a non-"VLAN Networking mode" (i.e. "Flat DHCP mode")?

So when I access through the OpenVPN client, I'll be 'placed' on my project/tenant network subnet. I got a fixed/private IP, i.e. 10.5.5.x/24.

I'm using OpenStack Grizzly with Quantum (Flat DHCP mode).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this. But being aware of openstack networking I can assure you that as long as your cloud pipe instance has a floatingip associated (be it vlan or flat mode) , you can do this. I hope you had figured this out yourselves as my answer comes too late. stackoverflow seem to be slowly filling up with more openstack people only recently.